# Does .htaccess redirect affects Google Analytics

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web, google-analytics, http-headers

I'm developing a website, and it's root content is on the /home/ folder.

As I'm going to use a htaccess redirect, to "drive" visitors from the root folder to the /home folder, my question is:

Does the HTTP referer header, will be lost in the redirect? I mean, if a visitor comes from www.onesite.com and a link redirects to www.mysite.com, then i redirect to www.mysite.com/home. Google analytics code, will catch up the referer as www.onesite.com, or www.mysite.com?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This question has been asked before:

[Will a 302 redirect maintain the referer string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158283/will-a-302-redirect-maintain-the-referer-string)

[Does 301 redirect always preserve referrer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398277/does-301-redirect-always-preserve-referrer)

Short answer. *Maybe*

Answer (score 0):

I hope this doesn't get marked as 'not constructive', but I think it will be your original website (www.mysite.com), however you can analyze the referrals on the www.mysite.com page instead of /home.

Comment: But that would require the page to be loaded, the .JS to be run, data to be sent to google, and then redirect... it's a "boring" time for visitors... =/